# Email is not sending using php

Tags: php, email

I am using the following code for sending attachments to the email...but i am unable to get the email..

I am able to get the message for successfully sending mail like " message sent " but the email is not going to corresponding mail id..

I don't where i do wrong....

Here is php file ...

```
             <?php

   if(isset ($_POST["send"]))
   {
        $upload_name=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
        $upload_type=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
        $upload_size=$_FILES["upload"]["size"];
        $upload_temp=$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];
        $message=$_POST["msg"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $to=$_POST["to"];


     if($message==""||$subject==""||$to=="")
    {
       echo '<font style="font-family:Verdana, Arial; font-size:11px; color:#F3363F; font-weight:bold">Please fill all fields</font>';
     }
    else
    {
    $fp = fopen($upload_temp, "rb");
     $file = fread($fp, $upload_size);

     $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
    $num = md5(time());
```

//Normal headers

```
     $headers  = "From: Info Mail<Info@example.com>\r\n";
   $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
   $headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
   $headers  .= "--$num\r\n";
```

// This two steps to help avoid spam

```
       $headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()."     TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
      $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";
```

// With message

```
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
   $headers .= "".$message."\n";
   $headers .= "--".$num."\n";
```

// Attachment headers

```
   $headers  .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type." ";
   $headers  .= "name=\"".$upload_name."\"r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
   $headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
   $headers  .= "filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\n";
   $headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
   $headers  .= "--".$num."--";
```

// SEND MAIL

```
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


 fclose($fp);

echo '<font style="color:#333333">Mail sent please check inbox and spam both <br /></font>';
   }
  }

 ?>
```

//HTML code for form details and adding attachment..

```
          <form id="attach" name="attach" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            //Html code for mail details
           </form>
```

I am getting "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent...." and also it is showing the "Mail sent please check inbox and spam both ".. what's the problem ?

Help me to fix this problem...

Comment: Keep in mind that you need a SMTP server running on the same server you are executing your PHP in order to send emails.

Comment: why are you turning off warnings for the call to `mail`? Remove that @ and see what warnings you get.

Comment: save your self a world of pain and stop using mail() use one of the libraries we all use instead: phpmailer, swiftmailer. learning css would probably help to :-)

Comment: If you are running Linux and you have shell access, try `mail` command on the commandine to see whether your mail settings are correct.

Comment: @Dagon I am new to php, how can i use phpmailer,swiftmailer instead of above using procedure.. give me some example or some explination..please

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As i am getting the message sent... but why can't i get the mail in corresponding email.. what's the problem?..help me..

Comment: each provides better examples on there own sites than i could, http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ and http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: just because you get the message sent, doesn't mean you don't get warnings. Remove that @ and see if you get any. If you don't: that's information you need to put in your post. If you do: that's information you need to put in your post =)

Comment: also note that `<font>` is only supported in the ancient version of HTML  that is used for rich mail. It hasn't been part of HTML since 1999. Literally (it was taken out in HTML4)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I removed the @ from my code..and i am  getting "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent...."   and also it is showing the "Mail sent please check inbox and spam both ".. what's the problem ?

Comment: edit your post to include that information, don't leave it in the comments. Other people need that info to answer you in a sensible way without having to read 10 comments to find it.

Comment: also note that just because it *says* "mail sent", doesn't mean it has. All your code does is close the file handle and then echo that string, without even bothering to check whether the mail was really sent. Very important.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so how can i fix it...

Comment: @Dagon But it is to complex for me and in php mailer they are using some zend framework.... how can i analyze it.. How can i perform on that....?Is there any simple way.. to do that..

Comment: then quit now, it you think either of those is 'complex' ;(

Comment: @Dagon I am asking help for using the phpmailer.. i downloaded the file" php-5.5.4-src " In this i found many folders.. Just am asking where to start.. in those.. and what to do next....  I will not quit.. If you want to help me help.. and Thanks for your replying...

Comment: it has a manual, what's the point of me reading it and re-typeing it out to you, read it, follow it.

Comment: @Dagon Ok....got it..

Comment: What's the mailserver log saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing bad data to the mail function. Head over to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and read the documentation that tells you how to use it.

Also note that it returns a boolean value that tells you whether your attempt to mail was successful so at the very least:

```
....
$success = mail(...);
if ($success) {
  echo "<p>mail sent</p>";
} else {
  echo "<p>error: mail was not sent.</p>";
}
```

so that your code isn't lying about whether it sent the mail or not.

As for your massive amount of data: comment it all off. Then progressive uncomment bits until it breaks. You have now found the problem and can solve it by looking at what you're giving the mail() function that it doesn't like.